# How to hide/show graphical emacs?

Tags: frames

I'm writing a screen-shot making function, something like org-screenshot.el [link](https://github.com/dfeich/org-screenshot/blob/master/org-screenshot.el) but with my own percs.

I'm looking for a way to hide emacs while the screenshot is taking place and show it up again after. It is done in org-sceenshot.el in the link, but I can't figure out which command does it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never mind, I figured it out by reading the code more attentivley:

```
  (make-frame-invisible)
  (call-process "import" nil nil nil myvar/img-Abs-Path)
  (make-frame-visible)
```